# Time-independent perturbation theory applied to the most general two-level system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, approximations, eigenvalue, two-level-system

My question relates to problem 7.4 in Griffiths intro to QM (3rd Ed). In it, we are asked to apply pertubation theory to the most general two-level system where the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H^0$ and the perturbation $H'$ take the form
$$H^0=\begin{bmatrix}E^0_a&0\\0&E^0_b\end{bmatrix}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,H'=\lambda\begin{bmatrix}V_{aa}&V_{ab}\\V_{ab}^*&V_{bb}\end{bmatrix} \tag{1}$$
where $\lambda$ is a small constant which will eventually be cranked up to one. Now by summing the above two matrices, we can calculate the exact eigen-energies which we determine (by setting the determinant to zero etc) to be
$$E_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}[A+B\pm \sqrt{(A-B)^2+4C}\,]\tag{2}$$
where $A\equiv E^0_a+\lambda V_{aa}\,\,$,  $\,B\equiv E^0_b+\lambda V_{bb}$ and $C\equiv \lambda^2|V_{ab}|^2$. So we can find exact solutions for the energies regardless of what value $\lambda$ takes on. The question then goes on to ask that we expand the exact energies to second order in $\lambda$. This is where my understanding fails me.   The energies $E_{\pm}$ in equation (2) are $exact$ solutions and they already contain a second order term of $\lambda$ (present in the constant called $C$).  So what does it even mean to expand equation (2) to second order in $\lambda$? I have even managed to find a solutions manual which goes on to apply the approximation shown in equation (3) below
$$E_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}[A+B\pm \sqrt{(A-B)^2+4C}] \Rightarrow E_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}[A+B\pm (B-A)\sqrt{1+4C/(B-A)^2}]$$
$$\frac{4C}{(B-A)^2}\approx\frac{4\lambda^2|V_{ab}|^2}{(E^0_b-E^0_a)^2} \tag{3}$$
But clearly this approximation has omitted the $\lambda (V_{aa}-V_{bb})$ term in the denominator. Why are we able to make this omission especially considering the term being ommitted is itself a second order $\lambda$ term.
Any help on this issue would be most appreciated!

Comment: Here the exact solution is extended in Taylor series to second order in $\lambda$,a nd compared with the result of applying general eprturbation theory to the second order in $\lambda$. Note that, since the diagonal elements in the PT are incldued in the unperturbed energies, this answer contains higher orders in $\lambda$ (in the denominator), and also needs to be expanded in Taylor series.

Comment: @RogerVadim Thanks for the response. Okay I can see how we taylor expand the square root $\sqrt{1+\frac{4C}{(B-A)^2}} $. We can get the result by simply noting that $\sqrt{1+x} \approx 1+\frac{1}{2}x$ for $|x|<<1$. But my problem is that we still have the $\lambda (V_{aa}-V_{bb})$ term in the denominator of  $\frac{4C}{(B-A)^2}$ which is for some reason omitted in the answer. Why can we omit it?

Comment: You can also expand the denominator: the PT answer and the exact answer will agree only for orders up to $\lambda ^2$.

Comment: @RogerVadim So we expand as follows : $\sqrt{1+\frac{4C}{(B-A)^2}} \approx 1+\frac{2C}{(B-A)^2}$. Writing this out with the defns of A,B and C we get $1+\frac{2\lambda^2|V_{ab}|^2}{(E^0_b-E^0_a+\lambda(V_{bb}-V_{aa}))^2}$. Even if we taylor expand the denominator, the $\lambda(V_{bb}-V_{aa})$ wont disappear? Maybe you could write your reasoning out in an answer which could show me what I'm missing?

Comment: I am now confused baout which denominator you are expanding - in your question it is not clearly delineated, what formulas come from the exact solutioon, and which from PT. Why don't you just do normal Taylor expansion: $f(\lambda) = f(0) + f'(0)\lambda + f''(0)\lambda^2/2 +...$?

Comment: @RogerVadim Okay I think I understand your confusion. In my question, I do not utilize perturbation theory even once. I first solve for $E_{\pm}$ exactly which yields a equation (2). The problem in griffiths then says you must expand equation (2) to second order (still no perturbation theory at all). The solutions manual I have makes the expansion/approximation shown in eqn 3 and I am still not sure how that approximation is valid. I did however do the full taylor expansion like you suggested using mathematica and got the correct result though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{4C}{(B-A)^2}=\frac{4\lambda^2\vert V_{ab}\vert^2}{(E_b^0-E_a^0+\lambda(V_{bb}-V_{aa}))^2}
&=\frac{4\lambda^2\vert V_{ab}\vert^2}{(E_b^0-E_a^0)^2}\left(1+\lambda\frac{(V_{bb}-V_{aa})}{E_b^0-E_a^0}\right)^{-2}\\
&\approx\frac{4\lambda^2\vert V_{ab}\vert^2}{(E_b^0-E_a^0)^2}\left(1-2\lambda\frac{(V_{bb}-V_{aa})}{E_b^0-E_a^0}\right)\, ,\\
&\approx\frac{4\lambda^2\vert V_{ab}\vert^2}{(E_b^0-E_a^0)^2} +{\cal O}(\lambda^3)\, .
\end{align}
In other words, keep the exact expression for $B-A$ and then expanding this in powers of $\lambda$ simply produces an extra term of higher order than second order.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to power through and do the Taylor series expansion. Here is what I get from wolfram alpha if you sub in the terms I think you should get the answer.

[image]